# Declarations in script setup return undefined variables after async call with top level await

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

My Nuxt 3 / Vue 3 component with `script setup` looks like:

```
<script setup>
    const content = await useFetch('/api/items/published').then((res) => res.data)
    const items = await content.data.items
    const issues = await content.data.issues
</script>

<template>
    <Gallery :items="items" :layout="layout" @sponsorModalOpen="sponsorModalOpen()" />
</template>
```

The variables `items` and `issues` are returned as `Undefined` presumably because they are not awaiting the result of the first async call with `useFetch` before being set. This seems unintuitive as I would have expected the `await` on both the `useFetch` operation and the variable declarations to block until the pre-requisite task has finished.

If I re-write the code to pass `content` directly to the `Gallery` component as below, it works:

```
<Gallery :items="content?.items" :layout="layout" @sponsorModalOpen="sponsorModalOpen()" />
```

though notable this only works with the optional chaining as it is presumably rendering initially with the prop undefined, then updating once the async fetch operation completes.

Am I using `await` wrong here? How can I ensure that the variables aren't set until the async operation completes so that I can manipulate them (specifically to re-order the results)?

Comment: Comps with async setup are supposed to be exclusively used with Suspense

Comment: @MikeM thanks, I had tried that initially (should have mentioned that in the question) but it still seems to return undefined. Suspect I may need to use `Suspense` as @estus-flask has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found to this so far is to do the sorting directly in the `then()` callback on the initial fetch as below:

```
const content = await useFetch('/api/items/published').then((res) => {
  const sortedItems = res.data.value.items.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.issueNumber - a.issueNumber
  });
  console.log(res.data.value.issues)
  const sortedIssues = res.data.value.issues.sort((a, b) => {
    const dateA = new Date(a.publishDate)
    const dateB = new Date(b.publishDate)
    console.log(dateA, dateB)
    return dateB - dateA
  });
  return {
    sortedItems: sortedItems,
    sortedIssues: sortedIssues
  }
})
```

It may be that using Suspense would also be a solution, but I have not yet looked into this.